# Cannot use wordpress inbuilt text editor

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying to edit website theme files in wordpress interface but when I update it, it gives me this error.

Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change by some other means, such as by using SFTP.

wordpress site health plugin gave me this error

The REST API request failed due to an error.

> Error: [] stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://winnie-logistics:80 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution)

and

> The loopback request to your site failed, this means features relying on them are not currently working as expected.
>
> Error encountered: (0) stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://winnie-logistics:80 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution)

How can I solve these errors?

Answer (score -1):

First,

You need to setup a "child theme" first. Changes to your child theme will not be erased when you update the parent theme.

You should not ever make changes to the parent theme files in wordpress.

Secondly, the error is talking about a DNS lookup error. You must add "winnie-logistics" to your host file in /etc/hosts **OR** disable the plugin that has added a hook to your wordpress installation to perform this lookup.

```
cd /path/to/wordpress  (folder containing wp-config.php)

cd wp-content/plugins

grep "winnie-logistics" * -R
```

Now whichever files come up, you have to either modify them, or disable the plugins that they are part of. enjoy.

Comment: ok,  but that doesnt make any changes in "site health" page. and interesting fact, i can edit only themes that are not active. what server configurations might couse theese errors?

Comment: So, wordpress has a system of hooks where plugins and themes can both add in additional code to other parts of the wordpress dashboard, site, posts, etc

Comment: You have to research into how wordpress hooks work then look through the theme files or plugin files to figure out which one is performing this lookup